# Saw tooth current source instead of constant current source

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, capacitor, current, constant-current

I saw this circuit and wondered how the capacitor would charge when the constant current source is replaced by, say, a saw tooth current source.

[image]

In order to find the voltage across the capacitor from time t=0s to t=1s, I have used the formula of V=Q/C and Q=I*t. By this formula I have used to calculate the voltage across the capacitor. Can I use the same formula when the current source is replaced by a square wave current source or a saw tooth current source of some frequency and amplitude? In that case, can I apply the same formula or how can I calculate the voltage across the capacitor in that scenario?

Can someone guide me.

Comment: Think about \$\mathrm{i_C=C\ dV/dt}\$.

Comment: or more helpfully, \$V_t =\frac{1}{C} \int_0^tI_t dt\$

Comment: I'm not able to understand

Comment: @Neil_UK, Oh, yes. Thank you. Would you please provide an example with values as an answer for my benefit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're a beginner, and since you haven't understood what Neil_UK's equation means, I'll try to explain what his equation is telling us in simple terms.

$$ V(t) = \frac{1}{C}\int I(t)\cdot dt $$

The \$\int\$ symbol (integral) is implying some sort of "accumulation", a "running sum", and the \$dt\$ part says that we are accumulating something over time, as time passes, as time t increases from 0 to some future value of t.

The term \$I(t)\$ is the thing being accumulated. In other words, as time progresses, we are accumulating electric current \$I\$ and adding its value right now to whatever we had an instant ago.

If current \$I\$ is always zero (0A), then we are accumulating lots of nothing, and after a while we will still have nothing. Zero.

If \$I\$ is always 1A, after each second that passes we will have accumulated an extra  1. After two seconds we'll have 2, and after three seconds, we'll have 3, and so on.

The term \$\frac{1}{C}\$ is a constant factor that multiplies whatever we've accumulated so far. If \$C = 1F\$, that constant is 1. The smaller the capacitance, the greater this multiplier.

In electrical terms, this means that the smaller the capacitance, the faster the voltage across it will accumulate for some given current through it.

I'll show how this works graphically, by pairs of plots. The first always shows the variation of current through the capacitor with time, and the second shows the voltage across the capacitor against time.

Let's start with a capacitor of value 1F, and a constant current through it of 1A:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the voltage across the capacitor rises at a rate of 1V per second, so after 5s the capacitor has accumulated a total of 5V.

Now lets reduce the capacitance to 0.5F, which should double its rate of accumulation of voltage:

[image]
[image]

Now the total voltage accumulated across the capacitor after 5s has doubled, to 10V.

What happens if we change the diection of current? Well, the voltage simply becomes an accumulation of negative current over time. Setting current to \$I=-1A\$, and still with \$C=0.5F\$:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, by passing a constant current of -1A through a capacitor of 0.5F, after 5s of time the accumulated voltage across the capacitor is -10V.

Your original question is about what happens if the current is not constant. For instance, what happens if the current through the capacitor consists of pulses of 1A, each lasting 1 second, and each separated by 1s? Intuitively you can surely see that when current is passing, the voltage across the capacitor will rise, and when no current passes (between pulses), there's nothing to accumulate, and the voltage will remain unchanged:

[image]
[image]

What if we have both positive and negative currents? Surely, if we alternate the direction of current in this way, the voltage across the capacitor should rise and fall? Let's see (be careful to note that the current is a square wave alternating between +1A and -1A):

[image]
[image]

Now we'll look at what happens when we push a current through the capacitor that varies in a sawtooth fashion. That is, it rises slowly from 0 to 1A, then falls sharply to 0V and repeats:

[image]
[image]

This requires a little thought to understand. At time \$t=0\$, current \$I=0\$. That means there's nothing to accumulate, and the curve of voltage against time is flat, horizontal. However, shortly after \$I\$ begins to rise, the rate of change of capacitor voltage begins to rise also. The capacitor accumulates voltage slowly at first. Eventually current becomes significant, and with it the rate of change of acuumulated voltage also increases, until it reaches its greatest rate of change when \$I=1A\$.

This demonstrates the meaning of the other formula, that Rohat Kılıç suggested in the comments to your question:

$$ I = C\frac{dV}{dt} $$

This equation says that the rate of change of voltage across the capacitor (\$\frac{dV}{dt}\$) is proportional to the current \$I\$ flowing through it. Hopefully you can see this relationship in *all* the above graphs.

Lastly I would like to show you what happens when you pass a sinusoidal current through a capacitor. Here I will use a current whose function is:

$$ I = sin(2\pi t) $$

That's a sinusoid of amplitude 1A, and frequency of 1Hz. The result is this:

[image]
[image]

As expected, as the current rises, rate of change of capacitor voltage also rises, and vice versa. Consequently, this voltage is another sinusoid, delayed by one-quarter of a period, or 250ms. In terms of phase, this is a phase shift of 90°. In other words, the output is a cosine!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I couldnt thank you more for your detailed and patient answer. Very much appreciate it

Comment: I have a question, in my original question, how to calculate the voltage at the end of 1s with the saw tooth current source of frequency of 1kHz? Could you tell me how to apply for this in the formula ?

Comment: @Newbie, solve the integral! As a hint, you can consider a sawtooth current as a repeated sequence of the function \$I(t) = kt\$, where \$k\$ is some constant. That is, current rises linearly with time, for a short interval. That's all I'll say here, because a comment can't possibly fit the whole answer, but you could raise another question.

Comment: I have raised the question over here - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/596569/calculate-the-integral-of-a-saw-tooth-wave/596572#596572. Could you please help

Comment: I have two more questions. Could you tell me how you got I(t) = kt? Isn't the function same as a ramp function? Or in other words, how to write the function for ramp and saw tooth? And the other question is that, we don't have to included the parameter of frequency while calculating? Is it?

Comment: @Newbie, yes \$I(t)=kt\$ is a ramp function, and it only describes the current for a single period. At the beginning of the following cycle, current returns to zero again, so you must integrate that function for one cycle period only, and repeat piece-wise. There is no finite continuous function that describes a sawtooth, because of the discontinuities, which is why I recommend piecewise integration. You could find the Fourier series, which would yield a continuous function of sums of sines and cosines for any t, and integrate that instead, which would be hellish. I'd go piece-wise.

Comment: thank you. Could you help me on how to find the voltage in the case of saw tooth current source for a frequency of say 1kHz?

Comment: @Newbie, I did my best to answer this on your new question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/596569/calculate-the-integral-of-a-saw-tooth-wave/598276#598276