# Charging of a capacitor using a Saw tooth current source

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, capacitor

This question is a continuation of the previous one over [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/591377/saw-tooth-current-source-instead-of-constant-current-source/591409?noredirect=1#comment1551133_591409)

[image]

Consider the sawtooth current source with 0 A offset, starting from 0 A, peak value of 1 A, frequency of 1 kHz.

How do I include the frequency parameter in the formula?

$$\mathrm{V(t)=\frac{1}{C}\int_{t=0\ A}^{1\ A} I(t)\ dt}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the limits of the integrals are time, not current.

> Consider the saw tooth current source with 0A offset. Starting from 0A. Peak value of 1A. Frequency of 1kHz.

I'm assuming this to be like "current starts at 0A, reaches to 1A linearly in 1ms (1/f) then drops back to 0A in zero time and the cycle begins afresh".

So the current equation will be \$\mathrm{i(t)=m\ t + n}\$ where \$\mathrm{n=0}\$ because there is no offset, and \$\mathrm{m=1A/1ms}\$ indicating the rate of change. So \$\mathrm{i(t)=t;\ 0\le t \le 1ms}\$.

> How to include the frequency parameter in the formula?

Integral is the accumulation of infinitesimals across the period. Therefore, you don't use the frequency directly:

$$
\mathrm{
v(t)=\frac{1}{C}\int_{t=0\ ms}^{1\ ms} i(t)\ dt=\frac{1}{C}\int_{0\ ms}^{1\ ms} t\ dt=\frac{1}{C}(\frac{t^2}{2}|_{0\ ms}^{1\ ms})=\frac{1}{2C}\ Volts
}
$$

The value above will be the final voltage across the capacitor after the first 1 ms of operation. If the capacitor is not discharged at the end of this period then the next 1ms-long charges from the current source will accumulate further 1/2C Volts across the capacitor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you tell me from where you got the i(t) = mt+n equation?

Comment: @Newbie From trigonometry: Equation of a straight line!

Comment: Oh, yes forgot. Thank you.