# Calculate the integral of a saw tooth wave

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, capacitor, current

My question is with reference to this question over [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/591377/saw-tooth-current-source-instead-of-constant-current-source/591409?noredirect=1#comment1551133_591409)

Suppose, I have a saw tooth current source with peak value from 0A to 1A with a frequency of 1kHz and I need to calculate the charge of the capacitor at time t=1sec, how to solve it?

Can someone help me with the answer.

Comment: Can someone please explain the math a little more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the discontinuous nature of a sawtooth waveform, there is no continuous algebraic expression (except an infinite fourier series) that describes it. You cannot differentiate or integrate discontinuous functions. Take for instance that point in a sawtooth current function when current drops instantly from 1A to zero. The derivative of this function at that instant is \$-\infty\$.

In such circumstances you may define a derivative or integral in piece-wise terms, wherein you partition a function into intervals for which the derivative or integral can be expressed algebraically. For instance, given an integral over some given interval, \$0 \le t \lt 3\$, you may partition it into a sum of integrals over shorter intervals \$0 \le t \lt 1\$, \$1 \le t \lt 2\$ etc.:

$$ \int_0^3 f(t) \cdot dt = \int_0^1 f(t) \cdot dt + \int_1^2 f(t) \cdot dt + \int_2^3 f(t) \cdot dt $$

As long as you choose intervals (pieces) for which you are able to describe the function algebraically and continuously, you can calculate the individual piece integrals, and add them. This is called piecewise integration.

So for a sawtooth waveform \$I(t)\$ with a freqency of 1kHz, and where \$0 \le I \le 1A\$, you must partition it into intervals that you can describe algebraically. Since each cycle of this waveform is a linearly increasing current, starting at \$I=0\$, and ending at \$I=1\$ one millisecond later, the simplest piece-wise description of \$I(t)\$ would be a sequence of ramps:

$$
I(t) =
\begin{cases}
1000t,  & 0 \le t \lt 1ms \\
1000(t-1ms),  & 1ms \le t \lt 2ms \\
1000(t-2ms),  & 2ms \le t \lt 3ms \\
& \vdots
\end{cases}
$$

This looks worse than it is. For each partition the function \$I(t)\$ is identical, because this is, after all, a periodic waveform. This will simplify things a lot, as you'll see.

For now you wish to know the accumlated charge on a capacitor passing current \$I(t)\$ over an interval of \$n\$ waveform periods \$T\$, for which the expression would be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta Q &= \int_0^{nT} I(t) \cdot dt \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The delta symbol is there because this accumulated charge will be on top of whatever charge the capacitor had to start with. \$\Delta Q\$ is the *change* in charge.

We partition this integral into pieces each \$T\$ seconds (1 period) long:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta Q &= \int_0^{T} I(t) \cdot dt + \int_{T}^{2T} I(t) \cdot dt + \int_{2T}^{3T} I(t) \cdot dt + \cdots + \int_{(n-1)T}^{nT} I(t) \cdot dt \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The big simplification we can make is because the integral of \$I(t)\$ over each partition interval is the same. This is obvious when you realise that the area under the current plot is the same for each interval, since this waveform is periodic. Therefore we can rewrite this as:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta Q &= n\int_0^{T} I(t) \cdot dt
\end{aligned}
$$

We already have a continuous function describing \$I\$, and a value for \$T\$

\begin{aligned}
I(t) &= 1000t \\ \\
T &= 1ms \\ \\
\end{aligned}

Now we just plug them in:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta Q &= n \int_0^{1ms} 1000t \cdot dt \\ \\
&= n \left[\frac{1000}{2}t^2\right]_0^{1ms} \\ \\
&= n \times 500 \times \left(10^{-3}\right)^2 \\ \\
&= n \times 500 \times 10^{-6} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The voltage change you would expect to see across the capacitor after n periods is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta V &= \frac{\Delta Q}{C} \\ \\
&= n \cdot \frac{500 \times 10^{-6}}{C} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw2Phh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, we [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Theory_of_operation) that:

$$\text{C}=\frac{\text{Q}}{\text{V}}\tag1$$

We also know that the voltage and charge are dependent on time, so:

$$\text{Q}\left(t\right)=\text{C}\cdot\text{V}\left(t\right)\tag2$$

And, we know that:

$$\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\text{C}\cdot\text{V}_\text{C}'\left(t\right)\tag3$$

Combining gives:

$$\text{Q}'\left(t\right)=\text{C}\cdot\frac{\text{I}\left(t\right)}{\text{C}}=\text{I}\left(t\right)\space\Longrightarrow\space\text{Q}\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\text{I}\left(\tau\right)\space\text{d}\tau\tag4$$

Using your data we find:

$$\text{Q}\left(1\right)=\int_0^1\text{I}\left(\tau\right)\space\text{d}\tau=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1000}\cdot1000=\frac{1}{2}=0.5\space\text{C}\tag5$$

Comment: Could you explain your last step?

Comment: Could you explain your last step? –